# How can I use a measure to determine the earliest date for a table visual's repeatedly listed entry while keeping all visual filters intact?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visual in Power BI, basically like this (I'm only using excel here as a general representation of the Power BI table):

[image]

The columns *Project Name*, *Priority*, *Referral Number*, *Project Start Date*, *Project Finish Date*, *Project Manager*, *Customer Branch*, *Customer POC*, and *Customer Org* all come from a table named *Projects*.

The columns *Task Name* and *Task Finish Date* come from a table called *Tasks*.

The *Projects* and *Tasks* tables are related.

The table visual is filtered by the *Customer* column from the *Projects* table using a slicer. It is also further filtered by these additional columns that are not in the visual but are from the *Projects* table, using slicers: *Project Status*, *Organization Group*, *Work Type*, and *Project FY*.

The table visual is further filtered by one more column that is not in the visual but is from the *Tasks* table, using a slicer: *Task Level*.

I need to keep all filters intact and determine the earliest *Task Finish Date* for each project (*Project Name*). I’m trying to use a measure.

I have tried:

```
EarliestTaskFinishDate = 
        CALCULATE (
            MIN ( Tasks[Task Finish Date] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( Projects, Projects[Project Name])
        )
```

But this doesn’t yield the desired result. It just duplicates the *Task Finish Dates* for each task instead of providing the earliest task finish date for the project.
I also tried substituting `FIRSTDATE` for `MIN`, which yielded the same result.

Further, I tried using variations of `ALLSELECTED` instead of `ALLEXCEPT`, but I didn't get anywhere with that either.

I've additionally tried the following and got the exact same result.

```
EarliestTaskFinishDate = 
VAR PN = IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Projects[Project Name])) > 1, BLANK(), VALUES(Projects[Project Name]))
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        MINX( Tasks, Tasks[Task Finish Date] ),
            FILTER('Projects', 'Projects'[Project Name] = PN)
    )
```

Of course, using `EARLIER` is not an option for a measure. I could definitely use some help please.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
EarliestTaskFinishDate = 
        CALCULATE (
            MIN ( Tasks[Task Finish Date] ),
                FILTER( ALLSELECTED ( Projects), Projects[Project Name] = SELECTEDVALUE(Projects[Project Name]))
        )
```

Comment: Thanks msta42a. Your recommendation makes complete sense to me, but I'm still getting the exact same result with this approach as before. The measure is just providing the `Task Finish Date` of each particular task as the `EarliestTaskFinishDate`, rather than providing the actual earliest `Task Finish Date` of *all of the tasks for the project* as the `EarliestTaskFinishDate`.

Comment: if you can post your sample data as plain text then I try (currently I don't have any sample to work and retyping takes too much time).

Comment: It looks like I figured out the answer: 

    `EarliestTaskFinishDate = CALCULATE ( MIN ( Tasks[Task Finish Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( Tasks ), VALUES ( Tasks[Project Name] ) )` 

*Project Name* is also in my *Tasks* table. This doesn't work if I use `Project[Project Name]` instead of `Tasks[Project Name]`. I don't know why exactly. I think I need to look at my table relationships if I want a better understanding. ...which I will.